# Is it a dictionary or a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I got the following JSON file and want to know if it is a dictionary or list. Maybe someone can help me.
Maybe someone can explain to me how to recognize that. I am new with Python.

```py
{
    "PIC_NAME": [
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ["URL", "PATH", NUMBER],
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try `type(obj)`

Comment: If that's the contents of the file, it's just text that represents a JSON object. If you *decode* it, the result is a Python `dict`, which maps `"PIC_NAME"` to a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts with a `{` and has `:` in it – it's a dict.

To be more clear, it's a dict with one key `PIC_NAME`, and that key's value is a list containing lists of length 3.

Comment: Technically it's not a dict or a list, it's JSON. JSON is its own distinct structure independent of Python. If you want to represent this data in Python, then yes you can do it with a dict as it has the same structure as JSON whereas a list can only represent a very small subset of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It is a dictionary, which has a list of lists as one of its values.

Answer (score -1):

python dictionary syntax

```
PIC_NAME = {"URL": "PATH": NUMBER,
    "URL": "PATH": NUMBER,
    "URL": "PATH": NUMBER,
    "URL": "PATH": NUMBER,
    "URL": "PATH": NUMBER,
    "URL": "PATH": NUMBER}
```